# few hotkeys not working and doing something else

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

So as the title said there are few hotkeys which are not working in blender, I am using version **2.83 in windows**. Whenever I press hotkeys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> etc., in order to apply subsurf modifier on the selected object I just go in front view or view rotates up or in side view respectively. Also in sculpt mode when I use hotkeys including number to switch brushes my view only changes respectively, is there a fix for the same.

Comment: In blender there is a difference between using the numeric pad and using the regular numbers at the top of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have Emulate Numpad turned on, toggle it and see if that clears up the hotkeys for you.

[image]